# getGeneratedKeys returning empty ResultSet after executeBatch

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to do batch inserts for a couple of records using a PreparedStatement. However, I keep getting false whenever I call next on my ResultSet

```
public ResultSet insert_into_batch(ArrayList<Movie> values) throws SQLException
{
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    ArrayList<String> added = new ArrayList<String>();
    String stmt = "INSERT INTO movies (id,title,year,director) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement psInsertRecord = conn.prepareStatement(stmt, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    for (Movie movie : values)
    {
        if (!added.contains(movie.getId())) {
            added.add(movie.getId());
            psInsertRecord.setString(1, movie.getId());
            psInsertRecord.setString(2, movie.getTitle());
            psInsertRecord.setInt(3, movie.getYear());
            psInsertRecord.setString(4, movie.getDirector());
            psInsertRecord.addBatch();
        }
    }
    psInsertRecord.executeBatch();
    conn.commit();
    conn.setAutoCommit(true);
    return psInsertRecord.getGeneratedKeys();
}
```

Comment: '`ResultSet.getGeneratedKeys()` returning false': no it isn't. It doesn't return a `boolean`. Your title and your question disagree. Please rectify.

Answer (score 0):

I see three potential problems with your code.

1. You insert a record with an explicit id, so no keys might have been generated. Generated keys are for when the database system generates the identifier, but your code generates it explicitly (some database systems will then still generate the result set, but not all, not sure about MySQL in this case).
2. You commit the connection directly after batch execution, as a result the generated keys result set (if any) created by the execute will already have been closed or relevant information cleared. Although I would have expected a driver to throw an exception when calling `getGeneratedKeys()` in that situation.
3. The JDBC specification states that it is implementation-defined whether `getGeneratedKeys` is supported for batch execution, so it is possible that it is not supported at all (but a quick look at the sources of MySQL Connector/J suggests it is supported).

Comment: Does committing the *transaction* really close anything?